# What does "Now all I take is ibuprofen, and that's two flights up" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, metaphors, rhetorical-devices

There's a conversation between Dr.House and a patient in an episode of *House MD* named *Lockdown*, where House tries to explain an issue with withdrawal of the drug he's been using for a long time to reduce his pain. Here is an excerpt of the dialogue:

> **Sick patient**: Bad pain day?
>   **Dr. House**: Bad pain month.
>   **Sick patient**: And since I'm not using it… If you don't want the morphine, you must have something of your own.
>   **Dr. House**: I was in rehab.  Had a little problem with the "something of my own."  Now all I take is ibuprofen, and that's ***two flights up***.
>   **Sick patient**: For the whole month?
>   **Dr. House**: The pain's migrated, I think the arterial wall is damaged.

*[House](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=house-md&episode=s06e16)*  Season 06, episode 17 – *Lockdown*
[Video link](https://watch-series.co/series/house-m-d-season-6-vhi-episode-17): scene begins circa 15:15

What does Dr. House mean by "two flights up"?

Comment: You see the word “flight” is modified by “two”, that is, a number, a quantifier. So it’s very likely a noun. Did you look the noun *flight* up in a dictionary? If so, what relevant definitions did you find, which would make sense in context?

Comment: Nah, having an offline Longman (Advanced Learner's) and checking the internet doesn't help me a lot.

Comment: Can you [edit] in the definitions you found for *flight* as a noun and your thoughts about why each definition doesn’t help or fit the context? That’ll allow us to give you more specific guidance.

Comment: I know **flight** as a noun form of **flying** and the fact that people often describe the use of recreational drugs as _being high_ or _flying_, my guess was that by **two flights up** House means ibuprofen is a stronger drug compared to the former vicodin he withdrew. But I'm not sure that fits correctly.

Comment: I wanted you to read the dictionary definitions again because I wanted you to get an internal, intuitive sense of more meanings for the noun *flight* than the ones directly related to *flying*. The sentence isn't related to flying or being high in any way. CMNEN got it right in his answer below. The sense being used is a *flight of stairs*. I was hoping when you re-read the definitions, that would stick out at you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen the show, but it would appear from context he is talking about "a flight of stairs" (i.e. the stairs between each floor of a building).

So when he says "that's two flights up" he means, that two floors above him in the building.

Comment: That makes sense... it may be that he's using it in a metaphorical sense, though. 'Two flights up' could mean the pain is now two 'levels' higher than before, or that he's doing two levels 'better' on some imaginary scale of good behaviour (I'd have to see the scene to know which).

Comment: The title of the episode is "Lockdown".  Presumably the stairs are not accessible.

Comment: You mean he has to go two floors up in the hospital to get more ibuprofen o.O?

Comment: @AshkanRanjbar Yes, that’s what he means. And what Dr House meant too.